# Calculating principal curvature directions on discrete mesh without quadratic fitting

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry-surface

I am working with 2d surfaces embedded in 3d, with a discrete triangulation, and would like to calculate to principal curvature directions (eigenvectors of the curvature tensor). What I already know is summarised in the following post: [How to get principal curvature of a given mesh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234127/how-to-get-principal-curvature-of-a-given-mesh). Basically, they talk about fitting points to a quadratic polynomial, and then diagonalising the obtained quadratic form.

My question is, is there any faster way of finding the eigenvectors? I have to do this over and over again, hence the need for speed. It is easy to find out the eigenvalues of the curvature tensor, namely the Gaussian curvature (using angular deficits) and Mean curvature (using the Laplacian). Are there any existing simpler algorithms for the eigenvectors?

PS: I am working in Python, if that helps.

Comment: The values of the curvatures don't give you any information on the directions, as they are rotation invariant.

Answer (score 0):

When you know an Eigenvalue `e` of a 3x3 matrix `M`, an Eigenvector is given by the cross product of two columns of `M - e.I`, which is low cost.

To avoid degenerate cases, it is better to choose the pair of columns that yields the longest vector, but this triples the cost.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid quadratic surface fitting and estimate principal curvatures and directions in a point of triangular mesh, one can use vertex normals in addition to vertex coordinates as described in the article [Estimating Curvatures and Their Derivatives on Triangle Meshes](https://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Rusinkiewicz_2004_ECA/curvpaper.pdf) by Szymon Rusinkiewicz.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74162108/7325599) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for this. But then, one needs a way to calculate the normal at each vertex. What's the best way of doing that?

Comment: Yes, one has to compute vertex normals before using suggested approach. If the size of triangles in mesh is more or less uniform, then the simplest approach with averaging of neighbor triangle normals works fine.